# stopping the default website of IIS

Tags: c#, iis

Does it have the same effect to stop the default website in IIS and giving the command line instructions:
net stop was /y
net stop w3svc /y

with respect to IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not the same. Stopping the default website inside IIS GUI does not stop the services as you do by net stop (which would stop every web site in IIS).